# How knn algorithm is implemented in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, implementation, knn

I want to know how the Knn algorithm is implemented in OpenCV. Where I can see this code?, is it easy to understand?, could someone explain to me in pseudo-code?.

Because I have implemented the following algorithm:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32970/K-Nearest-Neighbor-Algorithm-Implementation-and-Ov

But it gave me different results from the OpenCV function with the same training data. Particularly, the OpenCV function gave me the best results.

Thank you

Comment: You can find the implementation in the following link https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp

Comment: I couldn't find the constructor "CvKNearest" and the function "find_nearest"....